# Components for a WiFi enabled IR controller

Tags: remote, infrared, wifi

I don't have any experience with electronics really but I do have experience in programming.  I'm interested in writing a program to control my stereo, TV etc.  To achieve this I'll need a piece of hardware which is WiFi capable and can generate a range of infrared signals to control my TV, stereo and other infrared capable devices.  Given my lack of experience with microcontrollers etc, I'd probably find it easier if I could minimize the amount of work the hardware had to do and focussed it on converting data it receives via WiFi into infrared.  What components would I require and are there any relatively inexpensive out-of-the-box solutions which will have the majority of what I need without requiring too much additional soldering?  Also, at a high level, what way should the operation of such a device be architected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook up a RF/Bluetooth (cheap) module to your IR receiver, which usually requires a UART header (USB IR Toy's UART header is not supported in the firmware, only UART-to-USB bridge), or you can use some kind of USB-to-Wireless converter (USB IR Toy uses USB CDC/ACM).

So you need to check the connections in your IR receiver and wireless module (signal levels, host/slave configuration, etc). Probably your best bet is to get a USB-to-Wireless bridge module.

EDIT: If you want to make your IR receiver truly wireless, you probably should look for a way to power it and the wireless bridge module. Take a look at these links (can't post more than one link, so check second link as a comment below  ^.^):

[Parts for Solar/Bluetooth Hot-Swappable Unit](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/index.php?topic=759.0)

Comment: http://www.rachelselectronics.com/2010/09/sol_arduino-v1/

Comment: Bluetooth TTL Transceiver Module w/ Breakout (http://www.mdfly.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=428)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [USB Infrared Toy](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/USB_Infrared_Toy) (from the people who brought us Bus Pirate).

Of course, you'll still need the wifi part. A linux based router running OpenWRT could be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest solution would be a [Microsoft Media Center IR blaster](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=mce%20ir%20receiver) many types are available, note that some require you to connect external transmitter diodes, something with wifi running linux (eg a Raspberry Pi) and [lirc](http://www.lirc.org/). Lirc has a sensible API and a huge library of ir codes.

The traditional solution to this was the logitech harmony, but they recently shuttered their APIs.